# Jenkins getting list of files added or modified only

Tags: jenkins-groovy

We use a function to get a list of files changed so that those files can go through coding standards testings. However, it fails when one of the files has "changed" because it's been deleted. We don't want to include deleted files. This is our function:

```
def getChangedFiles() {
    def fileArray = []
    def changeLogSets = currentBuild.changeSets
    for (int i = 0; i < changeLogSets.size(); i++) {
    def entries = changeLogSets[i].items
    for (int j = 0; j < entries.length; j++) {
        def entry = entries[j]
        def files = new ArrayList(entry.affectedFiles)
        for (int k = 0; k < files.size(); k++) {
            def file = files[k]
            fileArray.add("${file.path}")
        }
    }
 }
 return fileArray
}
```

Is there a status I can check of the file? We are currently on Jenkins 2.289.2. Using the Git plugin.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Jenkins Core API version 2.289 it is possible to retrieve affected files from `ChangeLogSet.Entry`. [1] `ChangeLogSet.AffectedFile` has two methods `getEditType()` and `getPath()`. `getEditType()` returns whether the file is new, modified or deleted. [2]
I have modified following lines, the rest of your code looks good.

```
      def entry = changeLogSets[i].Entry
      def files = entry.getAffectedFiles()
      for (int k = 0; k < files.size(); k++) {
        if(files[k].getEditType() != "DELETE")
          fileArray.add("${files[k].getPath()}")
        }
      }
```

**Note:** I haven't tested it. Maybe it needs slight changes. 
[1] https://javadoc.jenkins.io/archive/jenkins-2.289/hudson/scm/ChangeLogSet.Entry.html 
[2] https://javadoc.jenkins.io/archive/jenkins-2.289/hudson/scm/ChangeLogSet.AffectedFile.html